# Automorphic Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

A Banach space $X$ is called *automorphic* if for every closed subspace $Y\subseteq X$ with $\dim X/Y=\infty$, every automorphism (= linear continuous isomorphism) of $Y$ can be extended to an automorphism of $X$.

The Banach space in the following problem is assumed to be separable and infinite-dimensional.

> **Problem.** Is every automorphic Banach space isomorphic to $c_0$ or $\ell_2$?

---

This problem was posed on 23 November 2022 by Anatolij Plichko on [page 39](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=39) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** Bottle of ''Тернівка''.

Comment: Do you mean "continuous linear isomorphism" instead of "linear isomorphism"?

Comment: Technically the answer is no, since a non-separable Hilbert space is a counterexample (and also finite-dimensional ones...). The conclusion should probably rewritten as "isomorphic to $c_0(X)$ or $\ell^2(X)$ for some set $X$", or it should be assumed that $X$ is separable and infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @YCor I think it is better assume that $X$ is separable and infinite-dimensional. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the Scottish book reference. This problem is due to Lindenstrauss and Rosenthal (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02787616.pdf?pdf=inline%20link). It is also explicitly stated in Lindentrauss-Tzafriri's book (Problem 2.f.11).

Comment: @BunyaminSari Indeed, this problem is very close to (but nonetheless different than) Problem 2.f.11 from Lindenstrauss-Tsafriri's textbook, which asks the following: Assume that $X$ is a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space such that for any $Y,Z$ are two isomorphic subspaces of infinite codimension in $X$ there exists an automorphism $\tau$ of $X$ such that $\tau Y=Z$. Is $X$ isomorphic to $\ell_2$ or $c_0$?